# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError |

Tags: java, error-handling

My java program is running fine on my Eclipse IDE, but when am trying to run the same ".java" file using my command prompt it is showing me an error as shown in the fig.

**Error: Could not find or load main class EulerianPathDirectedEdgesAdjacencyList
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/euler/EulerianPathDirectedEdgesAdjacencyList (wrong name: EulerianPathDirectedEdgesAdjacencyList)**

[image]

While am running the same code in my Eclipse IDE its working fine!

[image]

Please let me know, how to solve this.
Thanks!

Comment: wrong package name . try delete the "package xxxxx" in the java file.

Comment: my package is **com.euler** should I remove that line from my code??

Comment: you should read up on what packages do

Comment: please give full path name to java command like java com.euler.Euler.......List

Comment: @venkatramanhiregange I tried that, but didnt work. I wrote the below command after compiling it. **java com.euler.EulerianPathDirectedEdgesAdjacencyList**

Comment: can you please open jar and tell me w the content of jar?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command : java com.euler.EulerianPathDirectedEdgesAdjacencyList from the same directory where class file got created after running the previous javac command